# What happens to the returned value after exception is thrown in finally block?

Tags: c#, return, try-catch

I wrote the following test code, even though I was pretty sure what would happen:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Test().ToString());
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}

static bool Test()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sure enough, the program wrote "False" to the console. My question is, what happens to the true that is originally returned? Is there any way to get this value, in the catch block if possible, or in the original finally block if not?

Just to clarify, this is only for educational purposes. I would never make such a convoluted exception system in an actual program.

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [Is it legal and possible to access the return value in a finally block?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/304847/256431)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get that value, because only a `bool` is returned, after all. You can set a variable, though.

```
static bool Test()
{
    bool returnValue;

    try
    {
        try
        {
            return returnValue = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the catch block, got {0}", returnValue);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's messy, though. And for education purposes, the answer is no.

Comment: This is actually interesting in VB.NET where the local variable return result `Test` is predefined for you. I've just tested it and it is `True` in the equivalent `Catch` block, even when only `Return True` is used in the inner `Try` block. And, of course, `False` is returned by the function.